# How to add hostname and protocol with Zend 2 url helper?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I have problem with Zend2 url helper.
By default helper generate absolute path without hostname, example `/foo/bar` but i need url with hostname and protocol e.g. `http://example.com/foo/bar`.

```
$urlHelper->__invoke('foo',array(
        'fooparam' => 'bar',
))
```

is it possible with zend url helper? And if is possible how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `force_canonical` option as third parameter to url helper, eg:

```
$urlHelper->__invoke('foo', ['fooparam' => 'bar'], ['force_canonical' => true']);
```